# d3.js svg stroke applying to child element

Tags: d3.js, svg, stroke

This really grinds my gears. I'm trying to generate a bar chart to learn d3.js. Everything went well as I took things slowly. Day 1 for canvas, day 2 for bars, day 3 for scaling/margins etc. Until today, when I wanted to add an axis. To make everything easier to visualise, I removed the stroke of the main canvas (which was showing perfectly fine before adding the axis).

After adding the axis, the stroke is added to the bars, instead of the main svg containing everything. I looked at my code 100 times and I'm sure nothing is wrong, yet the result is not what I'm expecting. Any clues?

- no css links to any element of the chart, everything is generated by d3.js
- looking in the console, the stroke appears as a property of the main svg (container), but it seems like the property is being ignored

https://jsfiddle.net/vtw6pfwq/ (I had to change the dataset, but it works)

```
    <div class="datavis">
    </div>
    <script>
        d3.csv("data/demo.csv", function(data) {
            console.log(data);

            var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 60};
            var width = 750 - margin.left - margin.right;
            var height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
            var extent = d3.extent(data, function(d) {return +d.arg3;});
            var scale = d3.scaleLog().domain(extent).range([height, 0]);
            var yAxis = d3.axisRight(scale).ticks(5, "d");

            d3.select(".datavis")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .style("stroke", "#BDBDBD") // this is the non-working line, as you can tell, the stroke is applied to the green bars, not the main svg. Why??
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

            d3.select("svg")
            .append("g")
            .attr("id", "yAxisG")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + margin.top + ")")
            .call(yAxis)

            d3.select("g").selectAll("rect")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d,i) {return i * width / data.length;})
            .attr("y", function(d) {return height-scale(d.arg3);})
            .attr("width", function(d) {return width / data.length - 1;})
            .attr("height", function(d) {return scale(d.arg3);})
            .style("fill", "#4CAF50")
            .style("opacity", function(d) {return d.arg2;});
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: can you make fiddle? it's hard to answer that way

Comment: Hi. Yes, I did, sorry about that, I'm new around here. The link is in the main post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a comment here (was removed in the meanwhile), I realised how stupid my mistake was. An SVG element has no stroke, it has to be a CSS border.

```
.style("border", "1px solid #BDBDBD")
```

This now works, thanks for all the input!

Comment: I am the one who made the comment, I deleted it because I thought "I must be wrong, he doesn't mean a border".... So, at the end, all you wanted was a border, is that correct? Due to your question's title, I thought that you were asking why the axis was not inheriting the stroke property... besides that, it's not possible that a border was showing up before the axis and then disappeared because of the axis.

Comment: to be honest, the border was showing before, but only because I specified it correctly. when I added the axis, I removed a few things and upon re-specifying them, I was stuck on stroke instead of border...